# Untangling an interleaved log (text) file

Tags: regex, perl, text, sed

I have a file in plain text in this format:

```
On tick 95479102 total blocks 65
On tick 95479103 total blocks 66
On tick 95479104 total blocks 66
On tick 95479105 total blocks 66
On tick 95479106 total blocks 67
On tick 95479107 total blocks 67
On tick 95479108 total blocks 67
On tick 95479109 total blocks 67
On tick 95479110 total blocks 67
On tick 95479111 total blocks 67
On tick 95479112 total blocks 67
On tick 95479113 total blocks 68
On tick 95479114 total blocks 68
On tick 95479115 total blocks 68
On tick 95479116 total blocks 68
```

Due to operator error a couple of other logs have got mixed in with this, so now have later log entries which look like this:

```
On tick 95479541 total blocks 69
On tick 385 total blocks 124
On tick 130 total blocks 124
On tick 95479542 total blocks 69
On tick 386 total blocks 124
On tick 131 total blocks 124
On tick 95479543 total blocks 69
On tick 387 total blocks 124
On tick 388 total blocks 124
On tick 95479544 total blocks 69
On tick 132 total blocks 124
On tick 95479545 total blocks 69
```

I'd like to disentangle all this and as all the ticks are sequential I am sure it's possible to write a basic if cumbersome Perl script to do it - but is there an easier way or a CPAN library that might help?

Comment: add expected output for clarity.. and you are expected to **show** your own efforts to solve it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl one-liner should be enough to filter the noise.

```
cat file.log | perl -e 'my $last; while(<>) { /On tick (\d+) total blocks \d+/; if (!$last || int($1) == $last+1) { print "$_"; $last = int($1) }; }'
```

*Note that the script assumes the first tick in the file is a valid one.*

Comment: That's stretching the idea of a "one-liner"! It's also a useless use of `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing complicated with [`sort`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html):

```
sort -k3n yourfile
```

*(3 is the column you want the records to be sorted by, and `n` for a numeric comparison)*

Answer (score -1):

You can filter for lines with exactly 8 digits between "On tick " and " total" using `sed` like this:

```
sed -rn "/^On tick [0-9]{8} total/ p;" yourfile
```

**Explanation**

- `^` takes care that we are only matching at the start of a line
- `p` means print matching lines
- option `-n` means that no line is printed without an explicit `p` command
- `[0-9]{8}` matches exactly 8 digits, we need option `-r` for that

When you are satisfied with the output, you would store the commands output in another file.